# LinearGradient inside Rectangle is displaying blurred white borders

Tags: qt, qml

I am using `LinearGradient` as background for rectangle, but the left and right borders of the rectangle are a little bit white and blurred. How can I avoid this situation?

I have tried to set below properties on the Rectangle but it didn't work.

```
clip: true
smooth: true
antialiasing: true
```

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "#4f4444"
}

Rectangle {
    id: root
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    width: 355
    height: 90
    radius: 50

    LinearGradient {
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: ShaderEffectSource {
            sourceItem: root
            recursive: true
        }
        start: Qt.point(0, 0)
        end: Qt.point(parent.width, 0)
        gradient: Gradient {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#2a3254" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#0e1c57" }
        }
    }

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Click me!"
        color: "white"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it is smoothing the edges of the shape to blend with the Rectangle that contains the gradient (`root`). If you change that Rectangle's color to match what is drawn behind it, you won't see those edges anymore.

```
Rectangle {
    id: bground
    anchors.fill: parent
    color: "#4f4444"
}

Rectangle {
    id: root
    color: bground.color  // Match the background's color

    LinearGradient { ... }
}
```

Comment: yes you are right, thank you very much for the answer and explanation

Comment: You also don't normally want a ShaderEffectSource reference that refers to itself this way. It ends up rendering into its own source which is usually not what you want. Most of the time, you will see the LinearGradient be a sibling of Rectangle instead of a child in order to avoid this.

Comment: @DavidK.Hess thank you,  I will fix that too